# Generate XML with Phalcon

Tags: php, xml, export, phalcon

Need your help to generate `.xml` file with Phalcon) I need to get the result from view into my variable `$xmlContent`. In output file there is only `<?xml version="1.0"?>` Here is my drafts. Thank You

```
//in controller
public function exportAction(){

  $xmlContent = $this->view->partial('partial/xml/map', [
        'tks' => Tks::find()
     ]
  );

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadXML($xmlContent);

  $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
  $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="map.xml"');
  $this->response->setContent($doc->saveXML());

  return $this->response;
}

//in view
<tks>
{% for tk in tks %}
<tk>
  <type>{{ tk.tip_tk }}</type>
  <number>{{ tk.nomer  }}</number>
  <serial>{{ tk.seriyniy_nomer  }}</serial>
  <status>{{ tk.status_tk  }}</status>
</tk>
{% endfor %}
</tks>
```

Comment: Actually, I'am getting the result in variable `$xmlContent`, but it has `NULL` at the end

Comment: I understand that I can use `ob_start()`, `ob_get_contents()` in contoller and output everything there .. just need clear way)

Comment: does `$doc->saveXML()` returns null ? or output of phalcon is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should set view rendering level to `LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW`, content just outputs from `partial` and then we send header that's `xml` :) That's all)

```
//in controller
public function exportAction(){
   $this->view->setRenderLevel(Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
   $this->view->partial('partial/xml/map', [
     'tks' => Tks::find()
    ]
   );

   $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
   $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="map.xml"');
}

//in view
{{ '<?xml version="1.0"?>' }}

<tks>
{% for tk in tks %}
  <tk>
     <type>{{ tk.tip_tk }}</type>
     <number>{{ tk.nomer }}</number>
     <serial>{{ tk.seriyniy_nomer }}</serial>
     <status>{{ tk.status_tk }}</status>
  </tk>
{% endfor %}
</tks>
```